# Pass data between 2 already OPEN winforms (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have indeed read a multitude of post regarding this issue, however, I do see slight variations among them that do make my life very difficult. 
My situation is the following:
I have 2 winforms open (Form1 - Form2). Neither Form1 or Form 2 are created from each other. That is, I dont click a button to Show Form 1 or Form2. In fact, Form 1 is open and Form2 is instantiated via a third form and the third form is then closed. Se we are left with Form1 and Form2.
I want to transfer data from textboxes in Form2 to Form 1 upon clicking a button in Form2 which then closes Form2....while Form2 remains open. 
So far, the variations I see involve the instantiation of a new Form1 and then transfer the data in its constructor etc or creation of Form2 via ShowDialog. But this is not the case here.

I would appreciate ur ideas on this.

Comment: is there ever more than one concurrent instance of Form1?

Comment: no there isnt..just the one

Comment: maybe using something like websocket to pass data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use events to pass messages to disconnected entities. You can listen for events in Form1 and raise them from Form2. This is from memory, don't fully expect it to compile.

Create a class that is the "event hub".

```
public static class EventHub
{
    public static event EventHandler<EventArgs> formMessageHandler;

    public static void OnFormMessage(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        formMessageHandler?.Invoke(sender, e);
    }
}
```

In Form2 button click event raise the event. You can use the sender reference directly to access public members or you can put relevant data into an EventArgs.

```
EventHub.OnFormMessage(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

In Form1, maybe in the constructor, wire up a listener:

```
EventHub.formMessageHandler += some_method_you_write;
```

Now, when you click the button in Form2, Form1 will receive a reference to Form2 in *some_method_you_write()*. Or, you can actually use the EventArgs to pass data so you don't need to make any public controls on Form2.

Answer (score 0):

An idea, 
for exemple, in your Form1, you declare a variable like this.

```
          public Form2 frm2;
```

And when you instantiate your Form1 from your Form2 :

```
         Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
         frm1.frm2 = this;
```

Like this, in your frm1, you can access the Form2's controls like:

```
        this.txtForm1sTextBox.Text = this.frm2.Form2sTextBox.Text;



        Or you can get parameters via a public method of Form2. In your Form2 :



        public string GetMyParametersOrObject()
        {

           return Form2sTextBox.Text;

        }
```

In your frm1 :

```
       var text = this.frm2.GetMyParametersOrObject();
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: But do I add '''this.txtForm1sTextBox.Text = this.frm2.Form2sTextBox.Text;''' in teh constructor of Form1?
I get an error 'not set to an instance of an object". 
What is the action that will allow me to have access to Form2s controls?

Comment: No, you can leave your constructor by default. On my answer, Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
         frm1.frm2 = this; I set the frm2 after initialisation of Form1. Attention; In your Form2, you call Form1 frm1 = new Form1(); to initialise your Form1. And then, you call  frm1.frm2 = this; And then, in your Form1, if you call this.frm2.TextBoxOfYourForm2, you can get it.

Comment: But how do I call it in Form1?
The idea is to transfer the data upon closing Form2 and not to press any other button in Form1.

Comment: In this case, in your Form2, you declare a Form1 like Form1 frm1; and set it to an instance of Form1 when you initialise your Form1. And on Form_Closing event of your Form2, you can set any property of your Form1 like frm1.TextBox.Text = this.TextBox.Text;

Comment: U mean like this on the closing event/button : Form1 frm1 = new Form1(); (do I skip the frm1.frm2 = this; ?); frm1.TextBox.Text = this.TextBox.Text;

I am sorry but thre are so many self-referential statements that have me confused. 
I declared the variables frm1 and frm2 and initialized frm1 in Form2 closing event..but when u say setting it to an instance of Form1..what exactly do u mean?

Answer (score 0):

have a public static property with public getter and private setter in your Form1 class

```
public static Form1 Instance { get; private set; }
```

in your Form1 Constructor assign `this` to said property

```
Instance = this;
```

in your Form1 class add a public method to accept data passed by Form2

```
public void accept(object somePassedData)
{
  //do what ever you want with the passed data in Form1
}
```

in Form2 in your on closing handler pass the data to Form1

```
Form1.Instance.accept(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot. I went with the delegate-event approach and it worked.